# how to copy file from amazon server to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am working with s3 bucket. i need to copy an image from my amazon server to s3 bucket. any idea how can i do it? i saw some sample codes but i dont know how to use it.

```
if (S3::copyObject($sourceBucket, $sourceFile, $destinationBucket, $destinationFile, S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {


echo "Copied file";
                    } else {
                        echo "Failed to copy file";
                    }
```

it seems that this code is used only to bucket but not for the server?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy between S3 Buckets

AWS released a command line interface for copying between buckets.

http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://mybucket-src s3://mybucket-target --exclude *.tmp
..
```

This will copy from one target bucket to another bucket.

I have no tested this, but I believe that this will operate in series, by downloading the files to your system and then uploading to the bucket.

See the documentation here : [S3 CLI Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) for several years, and it's been very reliable. If you're using Ubuntu it's available with:

```
apt-get install s3cmd
```

You can also use one of the [SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code/) to develop your own tool.